# Using AMPscript to populate email, sending to a different DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

So here's my use case:
I need to send a weekly email containing all upcoming webcasts from our ecommerce site to our our subscriber base.

I have a file of website products and I have a separate DE of subscribers.
I am populating an email dynamically using AMPscript - pointing to product file DE; however, the product file is not sendable because there arent any associated subscribers. When I select the DE of subscribers in the send email automation, the automation fails because it doesnt have all of the necessary product data.

Shouldnt I be able to populate an email with product data from one DE and send to another DE of subscribers?

Comment: You really should include your code, otherwise we wont be able to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of [LookupRows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm), [Row](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/row.htm) and [Field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/field.htm), to query your product Data Extension and return data from there. There should be a field which is both in your sendable data extension as well as in the product data extension, in order to return your matching rows. Here is an example:

```
%%[
set @rows = LookupRows("products","customer", _subscriberkey)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
if @rowCount > 0 then
for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
var @productName
set @row = row(@rows, @i)
set @productName = field(@row,"productName")
OutputLine(Concat("Your product is: ",@productName))
next @i 
]%%
```

Comment: Not LookupOrderedRows? ;)

Comment: A matter of taste ;-)

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestions - I think we got it working now. I didnt realize that we could reference two different DEs in a LookupOrderedRows (or LookupRows) function.

Comment: You are welcome, @ZanahKagan. Remember to mark the answer as accepted